# Python sample code, I cannot run it correctly (Coding for Python, Playing with Pi)

Tags: python, types

I'm learning Python using magazine I picked up.

Here's the code that calculate value of Pi.

```
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext
import math
def calc(n):
    t = Decimal(0)
    pi = Decimal(0)
    deno = Decimal(0)
    k = 0
    for k in range(n):
        t = (Decimal(-1)**k)*(math.factorial(Decimal(6)*k))*(13591409+545140134*k)
        deno = math.factorial(3*k)*(math.factorial(k)**Decimal(3))*(640320**(3*k))
        pi += Decimal(t)/Decimal(deno)
    pi = pi * Decimal(12)/Decimal(640320**Decimal(1.5))
    pi = 1/pi
    return str(pi)
```

When it is executed, get this error message:

```
>>> calc(2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    calc(2)
  File "/Users/Documents/PythonCodes/CalcPi.py", line 9, in calc
    t = (Decimal(-1)**k)*(math.factorial(Decimal(6)*k))* (Decimal(13591409+545140134*k))
TypeError: 'decimal.Decimal' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
>>>
```

I see that type mismatch is the problem, but how can I fix it?

Comment: I am able to run it, getting answer as 3.141592653589793238462643386. Python version is 3.6.5

Comment: Thank you for running the code I posted and your reply. I am using Python 3.8.1 on Mac OS X 10.12.6 and using IDLE. I don't know why it's giving me an error.  pip is version 20.0.2.

Comment: I just added int() and it works now on my Python 3;

        t = (Decimal(-1)**k)*(math.factorial(int(Decimal(6)*k)))*(13591409+545140134*k)

Comment: Actually I could just do this way;
        t = (Decimal(-1)**k) * math.factorial(6*k) *(13591409+545140134*k)

Comment: It seems like the culprit was Mac OS version of Python IDLE.  I started to use VS Code, and now I can import module without issue. Also, I found out that installing Python 3.x by using an installer at python.org is not the best way to install Python3 on Mac OS X. 
This article helped me a lot.
https://opensource.com/article/19/5/python-3-default-mac